# Как добавить в массив ключ => значение?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой код:

```js
let ids = new Array();

let href = 'my_key';
let price = 'my_value';

ids.push({
  href: price
});

console.log(ids);
```

Как сделать чтобы задавался мой ключ для значения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let ids = Object.create(null);

let href = 'my_key';
let price = 'my_value';

ids[href] = price;

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: благодарю! это сработало.

Comment: @iKey, а галочку?

Answer (score 4):

Можно и через push

```js
let ids = new Array();

let href = 'my_key';
let price = 'my_value';

ids.push({
  [href]: price
});

console.log(ids);
```

Для объекта ключ можно записывать как вычисляемое свойство. Для этого ключ надо писать в квадратных скобках

**[Вычисляемые имена свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2)**